# In which of the following case , the function $f$ of bounded variation on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

1.The  functio $f :[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that , for all x,y $\in [0,1]$,
$$ |f(x)-f(y)| \leq 3|x-y|$$

2.The function $f$ is monotonically decrasing on $[0,1]$.

3.If for some non-negative riemann integerable function  $g$ on [0,1]
$$ f(x) = \int_0^x g(t)dt \ \ for\ \ all\ \  x\ \ \in [0,1]$$

Comment: In all three cases and you can prove it directly by definition. Just take a partition of the interval and calculate the variation.

Answer (score 3):

Let $P=\{0=x_0\le x_1\le\cdots\le x_N=1\}$ be a partition of $[0,1]$.

**(a)** Let us assume $f$ satisfies the condition from (a). Then

$$\sum_{n=1}^N |f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})| \le 3\sum_{n=1}^N |x_n - x_{n-1}| = 3\sum_{n=1}^N x_n - x_{n-1} = 3$$

So $f$ is of bounded variation.

**(b)** Let us assume $f$ satisfies condition (b). Then $x_{n-1}\le x_n$ implies $f(x_n)\le f(x_{n-1})$. So

$$\sum_{n=1}^N |f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})|= \sum_{n=1}^N f(x_{n-1})-f(x_n) = f(0)-f(1)$$

Therefore also in this case, $f$ is of bounded variation.

**(c)** Since $g$ is non-negative, we obtain

$$\sum_{n=1}^N |f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})|=\sum_{n=1}^N \int_{x_{n-1}}^{x_n} g(t) dt=\int_0^1 g(t)dt$$

Therefore $f$ is also in this case of bounded variation.